# How can I force macOS's "look up" feature to use my default browser to search?

Tags: search, preferences, web-browser, look-up

In system preferences, I have my default browser set to Google Chrome.

When I am using Chrome, if I select a word and force-click it, I get the usual dictionary pop-up, but if the word is not found in the dictionary the pop-up will have a button to "Search with Google".  Clicking this button causes Safari to open and the search is duly performed.

I can configure which search engine is used (and mentioned in the look-up pop-up) in Safari's preferences, but macOS appears to ignore my browser preference and always use Safari to do the search.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I can reproduce this, and would say this is a bug. Not writing as an answer in case someone has some trick up their sleeve.